# Is the induced map on the quotient space bounded?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, solution-verification, banach-spaces, quotient-spaces

Let $T: V \rightarrow W$ be a continuous/bounded linear map between Banach spaces. Let $J \subseteq \ker(T)$ be a closed subspace. Then I know that this induces a unique linear map on the quotient $\bar{T}:V/J \rightarrow W$ s.t. $\bar{T}\circ \pi=T$. I also know from topology that $\bar{T}$ is continuous w.r.t. the quotient topology on $V/J$.
We can also define a norm on $V/J$ via:

$$
\forall v \in J: \ \|v+J\| := \inf_{w \in J} \|v+w\|
$$
In particular is $J$ itself again a Banach space with this norm. I am now wondering whether $\bar{T}$ is always continuous w.r.t. this norm (or is the topology induced by this norm exactly the quotient topology?).

I managed to come up with this proof and was wondering if it is correct or if there is another, faster way to see this (perhaps by showing that the norm topology is the quotient topology):

\begin{align*}
&\sup \{\|\bar{T}(v+J)\|\ : \ \|v+J\| \leq 1\} 
\\ = & \sup \{\|T(v)\|\ : \ \|v+J\| \leq 1\} 
\end{align*}

Now by definition of the infimum $\|v+J\| \leq 1 \Rightarrow \forall \varepsilon > 0 \ \exists w \in J: \ \|v+w\| \leq 1 + \varepsilon$. Thus $\|T(v)\| = \|T(v+w)\| \leq \|T\|\|v+w\|\leq \|T\|(1+\varepsilon)$

Thus I get $\|\bar{T}\|\leq \|T\|(1+\varepsilon) \rightarrow \|T\|$ showing boundedness.

Comment: @pancini The quotient map has norm **at most** $1$. But I fail to see the relevance of that here.

Comment: Trivial quotient maps exist, though, so we don't want to say quotient maps all have norm $1$.

How does the fact that the quotient map has norm at most $1$ help deduce the boundedness of $\overline{T}$?

Comment: @jwhite ah I just misread. I thought $\overline T$ was the quotient map for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quotient topology is topology induced by the quotient norm. The quotient topology is such that $U\subset V/J$ is open iff $Q^{-1}(U)$ is open, where $Q:V\to V/J$ is the quotient map $Qx=x+J$.

It suffices to show that $U\subset V/J$ is norm-open iff $Q^{-1}(U)$ is. The quotient map satisfies $\|Q\|\leqslant 1$, so it's Lipschitz continuous, and $U\subset V/J$ open implies $Q^{-1}(U)$ is open. On the other hand, if $Q^{-1}(U)$ is open and $U$ is non-empty, fix $y\in U$. Fix $x\in Q^{-1}(U)$ such that $Qx=y$. Since $Q^{-1}(U)$ is open, there exists $r>0$ such that $x+rB_V\subset Q^{-1}(U)$. Here $B_V=\{y\in V:\|y\|<1\}$ is the open unit ball. I claim that $Q(x+rB_V)=y+rB_{V/J}$, so that $$U\supset Q(Q^{-1}(U))\supset Q(x+rB_V)=y+rB_{V/J}.$$  Thus the open ball $y+rB_{V/J}$ is contained in $U$, and $U$ is open. Thus $U\subset V/J$ is open in the quotient topology iff it's open in the quotient norm topology.

To see why $Qx+rB_V=y+rB_{V/J}$, first fix $u\in V$ with $\|u\|<r$. Then $Q(x+u)=Qx+Qu$, and $\|Qx+Qu-Qx\|=\|Qu\|\leqslant \|u\|<r$. So $Q(x+u)\in y+rB_{V/J}$. Next, fix $w\in Q/J$ with $\|w\|<r$. Then by the definition of infimum, there exists $u\in V$ with $\|u\|<r$ such that $Qu=w$. Then $Q(x+u)=y+w$.

Comment: The fundamental idea here is that the image of the open unit ball in $V$ is the open unit ball in $V/J$.

Comment: Thank you so much, knowing this makes things way easier! Do you know if my proof of boundedness of $||\bar{T}||$ is correct as well?

Comment: It's completely correct, and probably couldn't get any faster/simpler than you made it.